# HowTo: Conditional Page Break in SSRS 2008 in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, .net-4.0

I just migrated a project from .NET 3.5 to 4.0, accordingly the reports now use SSRS included in .net 4.0/VS2010.

Before conditionally setting a rectangles visibility did the trick for me. (inside the rectangle I put a rectangle with a pagebreak)

But this stopped working now.. any help appreciated

Comment: There is no such product as SSRS 2010.   The latest version is SSRS 2008 R2.

Comment: I didn't say there exists SSRS 2010!
Well it's SSRS 2008 R2 I guess, or whatever library gets installed with VS2010.
I noticed this change of behaviour only after migrating from VS2008 to VS210, that's what I describe above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of putting a rectangle with a pagebreak in a conditionally visible rectangle, with ssrs under vs2010 we can now directly add the pagebreak to a rectangle and the page break is shown, when the rectangle is visible.

conclusion: delete the inner rectangle and set the pagebreak on the outer rectangle solves the issue :)